# Open Source linux version of a Provisioner (like the Android and IOS Mesh apps)?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-mesh

This tag seems pretty dormant but maybe there are some still active.

Has anyone seen (or is this stupid for some reason) a Linux (Raspberry Pi) version of a Mesh Provisioner app?

I have created a pi-4 with recompiled kernel to get the crypto APIs, reinstalled the latest BlueZ and have tested the meshctl provisioning from the command line.

The next goal would be to have web based application that can manage the mesh network, add/delete nodes and configure them.

Any ideas on current similar projects that I can participate in?

Thanks

Comment: From reading the [BlueZ slack](http://www.bluez.org/contact/) workspace it would appear that `meshctl` has been replaced by `mesh-cfgclient` for configuration. Any application would use the [mesh API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mesh-api.txt) to communicate with the `meshd` running on the Linux system. An example of a node that supports the `on/off` profile is at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-mesh

Comment: Thank you @ukBaz.  I will look into getting that test to execute and learn more about it.